# Summing a list of dict with different keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of dict, with different keys and values, I want to aggregate on the value, the structure of the dict is as follows:

**Structure:**

```
for dic in doc_complete_views:
    for val in dic.values():
        print(val)
```

yields:

```
{'Algorithmic_bias': 4462}
{'Algorithmic_bias': 2391}
{'Algorithmic_bias': None}
{'Algorithmic_bias': 3167}
{'Algorithmic_efficiency': 7172}
{'Algorithmic_efficiency': 6271}
{'Algorithmic_efficiency': 8612}
{'Algorithmic_efficiency': 8277}
{'Algorithmic_efficiency': 6467}
{'Algorithmic_efficiency': 7070}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{'Algorithmic_bias': 10020}
{'Algorithmic_efficiency': 43869}
```

**Code Used:**

```
count={}
final_count = {}
for index in range(len(doc_complete_views)):
    for a,b in doc_complete_views[index].items():
        for i,j in b.items():
                try:
                    count[i] += j 
                except KeyError:
                    count[i] = j
    final_count[index] = count                  

# print the final array
print(final_count)
```

**Problem:**

The above code fails due to None for values

**Question:**

Is there a way to sum the values and ignore None while I am iterating over list of dictionary (the place where I am printing the structure)

**Structure of List of Dict:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, 
{datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 1, 0, 0): {'Algorithmic_bias': 3306}, 
datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 1, 0, 0): {'Algorithmic_bias': None}, 
datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 1, 0, 0): {'Algorithmic_bias': None}, 
datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 1, 0, 0): {'Algorithmic_bias': 1843}, 
datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 1, 0, 0): {'Algorithmic_bias': 3237}, 
datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 1, 0, 0): {'Algorithmic_bias': None}, 
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 1, 0, 0): {'Algorithmic_bias': 2837}, 
datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 1, 0, 0): {'Algorithmic_bias': 1950}, 
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 1, 0, 0): {'Algorithmic_bias': 3816},
```

Comment: Sure its a messy file but I can print a sample

Comment: Thanks. It's still a bit unclear--can you edit it to show a copy-pasteable structure that I can use in my code? If the values list after `yields:` is accurate, I can just use that.

Comment: Yield is the structure as is

Comment: It would help if you posted a [mre] including `doc_complete_views`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and simple `if` condition:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# doc_complete_views = ...
res = defaultdict(int)

for d in doc_complete_views:
    for sub_d in d.values():
        for k, v in sub_d.items():
            if v is not None:
                res[k] += v

final_lst = [{k:v} for k,v in res.items()]
print(final_lst)
```

The output:

```
[{'Algorithmic_bias': 10020}, {'Algorithmic_efficiency': 43869}]
```

Comment: I noticed that. I think there's some confusion in the data structures. I think you're producing the expected output, but it's unclear to me why that sort of structure would be desirable. Seems like a dict is the proper choice, but I'll leave it up to OP!

Comment: @ggorlen, I guess he wanted to eventually obtain a result similar to the initial structure (list of dicts) but with aggregations

Comment: Yeah, that seems totally plausible. I'll upvote here but I'm curious to see how it all ultimately works out in terms of desired results. My approach is also assuming there's only one key per dict, which also suggests that the structure organization is unusual or I'm making a bad assumption.